# How do I create a dropdown menu in CSS if the element positioning is already affected by the container div?

Tags: html, css

This is the css:

```css
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#header h3 {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#header a {
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 10px 20px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
   <h3>Company name</h3>
   <a href="#">Options</a>
</div>
```

With the above, the header is in place, the name of company is in place (to the left of the header), and the Options is to the rightmost of the header.

My problem now is, if I create a dropdown menu, I would have to wrap (?) the Options or put it in another `<div></div>` which has `position: relative` because the dropdown menu needs to be `position: absolute`. But when I try to do that, the whole thing messes up. Options is no longer at the right but at the left. I have tried looking at tutorials but mostly they are basic dropdown tutorials or basic positioning tutorials.

Can anyone help me position these elements properly? Or at least point me to the right direction. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share code when u do the dropdown menu. Can't you set the position?

Comment: As well as the drop down, we also need to see what you currently have with the options on the right

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap your header id div into another div, give the `position:fixed` property-value pair (pvp) to that wrapper div. Then, use `position:relative` on your header, `position:absolute` on your options anchor, and position the option anchor as you want with the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` css properties. A lil crash course:

`position:absolute` tells element X to place it on top of the first of its parent elements (walking the DOM-tree upwards) which has the `position:relative` pvp. Then, you can use `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` css properties on your element X to place it with the provided distancing from the respective border of its relative container.

Example:

```
<div id="header">
<p class="elem"></p>
</div>
```

```
#header {
  position:relative;
}

.elem {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
```

This example will place the paragraph "elem" on top of the "header" div, with 10px of distance between the top border of the header div and the top border of the elem paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for this. I managed to figure it out. The wrapping the div in another div did the trick.

Comment: no worries, glad could help:) plz don't hesitate in accepting and / or upvoting answers you considered useful :)